# ¿código para agregar filtros a un datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en c# y necesito agregar filtros por columna a un DatagridView utilizo windowsForms. 
Tengo Donet y estoy probando dataGridViewX

mi codigo que he hecho hasta ahorita es :

```
var informacionDepartamentos = informacion.DepartamentosInfo();
BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = informacionDepartamentos;
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = source1;
```

¿cual seria el código o en su caso el control correcto para poder utilizar filtros?

Algo como la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor mira [ask]. Que probaste? buscaste? hiciste hasta ahora? es winform o wpf?

Comment: Hmm...`source1.Filter=...`? O `((BindingSource)dataGridViewX1.DataSource).Filter = ..`?

Comment: Algo como la imagen que acabo de poner

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo este código, puedes adaptarlo a tu proyecto.

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TipoLote, Etapa, Codigo, Rubro, Grupo, Tipo, Fuente, Sistema, Observacion, Obligatorio, Automatico, ClaveFuente, FijoVariable FROM Produccion.EstructuraCostosProduccion WHERE (TipoLote = 'P') AND(Etapa = 'P')", sqlCon);
                sqlCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
                sqlAdapter.UpdateCommand = sqlCommand.GetUpdateCommand();
                sqlAdapter.InsertCommand = sqlCommand.GetInsertCommand();
                sqlAdapter.DeleteCommand = sqlCommand.GetDeleteCommand();
                dsConsulta = new DataSet();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dsConsulta, "EstructuraCostosProduccion");
                //dgvTest.DataSource = dsConsulta.Tables["EstructuraCostosProduccion"];


                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dsConsulta.Tables["EstructuraCostosProduccion"];
                dsConsulta.BeginInit();
                dgvTest.DataSource = bs;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in dgvTest.Columns)
                    item.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(item.HeaderCell);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

y queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]